# Show image instead of url via CSS

Tags: css, attr

I have:

`<a href="/media/media/about-logo.png">media/about-logo.png</a>`

I can do:

`a {
content: url(/media/media/about-logo.png);
}`

I need:

`a {
content: url( attr(href) );
}`

which does not work.

I need css to take text inside href and use it as an url, without hardcoding it.

Comment: No feasible way to do this with CSS.  Perhaps SASS, but only by hacking it/compiling on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to accomplish this with pure CSS and HTML. You'll need to use JavaScript. I'm using jQuery here for simplicity.

```
$("a").each(function () {
   $(this).css('content', 'url('+$(this).attr('href')+')');
});
```

At this point though, you might as well just use `.text` which would have an equivalent result.

```
$("a").each(function () {
   $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
});
```